# D3 v4 with SystemJS and TypeScript

Tags: d3.js, typescript, systemjs

I am trying to setup the newest version of d3 with SystemJS and TypeScript but seems like some puzzles don't fit together quite nice on my side.

**Summary**

Basically after I installed all dependencies and @types to node_modules I configured SystemJS to load those dependencies.

Now the behavior is totally strange, like:

- By using `import * as d3 from 'd3';` I receive `ModuleNamespace`
- By using `import d3 from 'd3';` I receive proper d3 object, but TS is complaining:

  - `Module '"ABSOLUTE_PATH/node_modules/@types/d3/index"' has no default export.' at: '2,8' source: 'ts'`

**Code**

*systemjs.config.js*

```
(function () {
  SystemJS.config({
    paths: {
      'npm:': 'node_modules/'
    },
    packages: {
      app: {
        main: './main.ts',
        defaultExtension: 'ts',
        meta: {
          '*.ts': {
            loader: 'ts'
          }
        }
      },
      ts: {
        main: 'plugin.js'
      },
      typescript: {
        main: 'lib/typescript.js',
        meta: {
          'lib/typescript.js': {
            exports: 'ts'
          }
        }
      },

      'd3': { "main": 'build/d3.min.js', "defaultExtension": "js"},
      'd3-array': { "main": 'build/d3-array.min.js', "defaultExtension": "js"},
      'd3-axis': { "main": 'build/d3-axis.min.js', "defaultExtension": "js"},
      'd3-collection': { "main": 'build/d3-collection.js', "defaultExtension": "js"},
      'd3-color': { "main": 'build/d3-color.min.js', "defaultExtension": "js"},
      'd3-dispatch': { "main": 'build/d3-dispatch.min.js', "defaultExtension": "js"},
      'd3-ease': { "main": 'build/d3-ease.min.js', "defaultExtension": "js"},
      'd3-format': { "main": 'build/d3-format.min.js', "defaultExtension": "js"},
      'd3-interpolate': { "main": 'build/d3-interpolate.min.js', "defaultExtension": "js"},
      'd3-path': { "main": 'build/d3-path.min.js', "defaultExtension": "js"},
      'd3-scale': { "main": 'build/d3-scale.min.js', "defaultExtension": "js"},
      'd3-selection': { "main": 'build/d3-selection.min.js', "defaultExtension": "js"},
      'd3-shape': { "main": 'build/d3-shape.min.js', "defaultExtension": "js"},
      'd3-time': { "main": 'build/d3-time.min.js', "defaultExtension": "js"},
      'd3-time-format': { "main": 'build/d3-time-format.min.js', "defaultExtension": "js"},
      'd3-timer': { "main": 'build/d3-timer.min.js', "defaultExtension": "js"},
      'd3-transition': { "main": 'build/d3-transition.min.js', "defaultExtension": "js"}

    },
    map: {
      app: 'src',

      'ts':                        'npm:plugin-typescript/lib',
      'typescript':                'npm:typescript',

      'd3':                        'npm:d3',
      'd3-array': 'npm:d3-array/',
      'd3-axis': 'npm:d3-axis/',
      'd3-collection': 'npm:d3-collection/',
      'd3-color': 'npm:d3-color/',
      'd3-dispatch': 'npm:d3-dispatch/',
      'd3-ease': 'npm:d3-ease/',
      'd3-format': 'npm:d3-format/',
      'd3-interpolate': 'npm:d3-interpolate/',
      'd3-path': 'npm:d3-path/',
      'd3-scale': 'npm:d3-scale/',
      'd3-selection': 'npm:d3-selection/',
      'd3-shape': 'npm:d3-shape/',
      'd3-time': 'npm:d3-time/',
      'd3-time-format': 'npm:d3-time-format/',
      'd3-timer': 'npm:d3-timer/',
      'd3-transition': 'npm:d3-transition/'
    },
    typescriptOptions: {
      module: "system",
      typeCheck: true,
      tsconfig: true
    },
    transpiler: 'ts'
  });
})();
```

*tsconfig.json*

```
{
   "compilerOptions": {
      "target": "es5",
      "module": "commonjs",
      "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
      "experimentalDecorators": true,
      "rootDir": ".",
      "baseUrl": ".",
      "moduleResolution": "node"
   }
}
```

*package.json*

```
{
  "name": "testing",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/core-js": "^0.9.35",
    "@types/d3": "^4.5.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.2",
    "plugin-typescript": "^6.0.4",
    "typescript": "^2.1.6"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "d3": "^4.6.0",
    "systemjs": "^0.20.9"
  }
}
```

Comment: Well, I guess this is not the reply you are looking for, but why SystemJS, in particular manually configured? JSPM could help in the configuration, and bundlers such as Webpack or Rollup (instead of SystemJS) made a great job for me. That's my two cents about it, can't provide much help...

Comment: Hi @HuguesStefanski, in fact I am now using webpack instead :)

Comment: Any better luck? Or still struggling?

Comment: With webpack everything is just fine. For the configuration above I stopped trying due to lack of time :)

Comment: Okay that's good to know